# Denying user permission in Django

Tags: django, django-users, django-permissions

I have a short question - is there a way to DENY already given permission ?

I have a 2 cases where i'll want to use that feature:

1, i have a user that is in particular group, which has some regular permissions, but i want to (temporary) remove some permissions from that group - like "add" but keep rest of them untouched (edit, delete,.. )

2, same group as above, has permissions to my 4 custom apps, but i want to "ban" user from one of them, and leave those 3 untouched

So no i think that simple denying feature could be  a proper way to do this and keep it easy to maintain in future (no need to have multiple groups etc)
Or maybe someone can guide me to a different and smarter way to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance for any reply.